# how to create dynamic list in android

Tags: android

Please don't give negative marking as i am new to android.
Till now i understood that we use adapters to set items in list.
And on onclicklisteners we can write the code we want to behave.
But i have a pop-up having 4 buttons in xml.
[image: It looks like this]

I want an adapter such that if i have 3 languages then only 3 buttons will be visible and if i have 7 languages then it should scroll on rightarrow click.
The xml files are as follows:
popuplang:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="@dimen/popup_w"
android:layout_height="@dimen/popup_h"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:background="@color/popupbg" >

<TextView
    style="@style/popuptitletxt"
    android:text="Change Language" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/infobtn"
    style="@style/headerbtn"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:src="@drawable/close_ic" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="153dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageButton
        style="@style/seekbarbtn"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_prev" />

   <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="@dimen/poplangbtn_contw"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <include layout="@layout/popup_langbtn_aod" />

            <include layout="@layout/popup_langbtn_aod" />
        </LinearLayout>
   </HorizontalScrollView>

    <ImageButton
        style="@style/seekbarbtn"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:rotation="180"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_prev" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and popuplangbtn.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/langbtn1"
    style="@style/poplangbtn"
    android:text="language1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/langbtn2"
    style="@style/poplangbtn"
    android:text="language2" />
```

please help me in this i am totally new to this